# How can I force IntelliJ-IDEA to highlight unchecked conversions that can appear while using java generics?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using generics in my code and I would like to be warned about potential unchecked conversions in the editor (before compiling), as of now IntelliJ-IDEA  can detect and warn some mistakes I might have in the code as I am writing it. However, unchecked conversions are never highlited and can only be detected after compiling only if the conversion between objects is not valid.

For example, if I have the generic type `Foo<T extends Bar>` I would like the code editor to highlight the text (underlining it for example) whenever this kind of assignment appears:

> `Foo<BarImplementation> b = new Foo()`

I have already tried going to `ctrl + alt + s ->  Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Errors and Warnings` and all of the warnings have their dedicated color shceme.

Comment: That's not an unchecked conversion: it's a usage of raw types. Unchecked conversion would be something like `Foo<BarImplementation> b = f;`.

Comment: Edited the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `Java | Compiler issues | Unchecked warning` inspection enabled in `Preferences | Editor | Inspections`? It is normally enabled by default, but maybe you disabled it?

Comment: I had it enabled but I thought unchecked conversion fell into the weak warning category, The warning default highlight didn't underline it and the color was similar to the one used to highlight selected code so it didn't look like it was highlighted.

Comment: It is possible to change the way warnings are highlighted in the editor in the settings of the inspection.